# Increment model attribute with update! method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In my app when user failed the Legal Test I should change their status to `inactive`, current date to `status_updated_at` and increment `failed_attempts`. Normally I would user something like:

```
  current_user.update!(
    status: 'inactive',
    failed_attempts: +1,
    status_updated_at: Date.current
    )
```

But is there a syntax to use built-in method like `increment` to be `current_user.update!( ... ,increment!(:failed_attempts)...),` ?

I don't know but using `counter_cache` is probably overkill since the User will have only 2 to 5 attempts.

Comment: `counter_cache` is probably not doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a possibility of race condition (i.e. model instance is holding  a stale value compared to the one in database), so one can use [`update_counters`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/ClassMethods.html#method-i-update_counters) with `transaction`:

```
transaction do
  current_user.class.update_counters(current_user.id, failed_attempts: 1)
  current_user.update(status: :inactive, status_updated_at: Date.current)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a one shot possibility. You can try doing this:

```
current_user.increment(:failed_attempts)
current_user.update_attributes(status: 'inactive', status_updated_at: Date.current)
current_user.save!
```

or this:

```
current_user.update!(
  status: 'inactive',
  failed_attempts: (current_user.failed_attempts || 0) + 1,
  status_updated_at: Date.current
)
```

Comment: Both these are racy. potashin's answer gives a more reliable approach.